# Invalid Syntax using DLookUp

Tags: ms-access

Fiddling around with the DLookUp Function in MS Access and I was pretty confident in what I had written but I guess not since it's yelling at me again... I'm using a DLookUp as a control source for a text box where I'm trying to get the Month from another text box as one of the criteria fields. Hopefully a fresh pair of eyes can point me in the right direction of what's wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

```
=DLookUp("Format([QA_Overall],'Percent')","tblScorecard","[Audit Month]='"&[Forms]![Copy Of frmScorecard]![txtMonth]&"'" And [Region]=10")
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: Initially I got an error saying invalid syntax, but I added in a test record changing the month from Jan to Feb to see if the number changes but it doesn't :/

Comment: so are you still receiving the syntax error now?

Comment: Also, could you maybe better explain what you are trying to do with the field after you pull it from the text box? what is this criteria field?

Comment: Oh no I think I accidentally added an " in front of the ' but was able to catch it. But it's not dynamic like I had expected it to be unfortunately.

Comment: So did you solve your issue?

Comment: So basically, I have a table with 10 regions and their QA scores. The goal is to display the % from each region in the appropriate text box with the criteria fields being Audit Month and Region. Currently, in the DLookUp, I have the [Audit Month] = 'Jan'. I'm trying to make it dynamic so that the Audit Month criteria in the DLookUp would use the value of txtMonth if that makes sense.

Comment: Hmm I guess the initial issue lol. It's like a hydra where you fix one thing and two more pop up

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is happening because of the Region Criteria. Try something like the below:

```
=DLookup("Format([QA_Overall],'Percent')","tblScorecard","[Audit Month]=" & [Forms]![Copy Of frmScorecard]![txtMonth] & " AND [Region] = 10")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Edit: I have changed the criteria. Try this Version.

Comment: Are you writing that for VBA? Because I'm currently just putting this DLookUp in the controll source of the text box. Also, I did try your criteria field and it results in a #Name?

Comment: Please see the answer again, i have altered the code

Comment: Hm gives me the #Error in the cell. I might just have to suck it up and manually change it each month rather than have it dynamic lol.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't be more help. I tried, haha. It would be easier if i could see it all first hand and been working with it for awhile. Try getting it to display with Both different criteria, but by themselves to see if they work. Then combine once you know that they both work. That is all the more i can suggest.

Comment: Oh no worries, I sincerely appreciate your time and effort! I'll try that out your suggestion though, thanks :)